# How to get rid of lines on edges of triangles in generated mesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, mesh, uv-mapping

I made a procedurally generated map, but I think I have some problem with uv's.

This is what problem looks like:

[image: model with visible unwanted lines]

This is what my code for uv's of one tile looks like:

```cs
Vector2 u = new Vector2((float)textureID / TextureCount, 0.0f);
UVs.Add(u + new Vector2(1.0f/ TextureCount, 1.0f));
UVs.Add(u + new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));
UVs.Add(u + new Vector2(1.0f / TextureCount, 0.0f));
UVs.Add(u);
```

Vertices of each tile are ordered top-right, top-left, bottom-right, bottom-left in vertex array.

This is what the texture I use for testing looks like(5 squares of color and 3 transparent ones):

[image: texture for testing]

I'm using unity and lines are not visible in editor, only in play mode.

How to get rid of those ugly lines I got there?

Comment: How is your grid being build? _Besides but not the question, having a square texture is always easier for the gpu, as it will always reserve a square map for it._

Comment: All tiles are placed on grid of certain density. I run bfs on this grid to decide where tiles should be placed. When I decide that tile should be in certain place I add 4 vertices/uvs and 2 triangles. If S would be size of the square on the grid, then vertices would be placed on :(S/2,S/2), (-S/2,S/2), (S/2,-S/2), (-S/2,-S/2) relative to the position in which I decided to place the tile. I don't know if that's what you're asking about tho

Comment: Think it will have something to do with your shader. It seems one tile grabs a bit from the next tile in the atlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that when generating mipmaps colors bleed through. Adding some padding in atlas solves the problem
http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding